# how enable/disable push notification with FCM

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use the firebase_messaging package and I want to use the Switch widget to enable and disable permissions for notifications and I don't quite understand how to do it
There was an idea to unsubscribe and subscribe to topics, but I don't like it

Comment: That's how push notifications work, you choose to subscribe to messages sent to a specific token or not. Do you have any ideas on how else you'd _not_ get a push notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enable or disable the permissions, all you can do is open the settings screen and ask the user to do it. The alternative is to subscribe/unsubscribe from topics as you mentioned.